# ngFor over nested map in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I want to iterate over a nested map to get the values out of a list in the second map.

Map:

```
public groupedItemMap: Map<string, Map<string, ItemSearchResult[]>>;
```

Map structure:

```
Map
--[[Entries]]
----0
-------key - number (if occured once or is duplicate)
-------value - Map
---------[[Entries]]
-----------key - itemNumber
-----------value - List of object(s) with parameters 'id',..'name' and so on and same itemNumber

++++++++++++if itemNumber is different there are more objects of the same type with different itemNumber
-----------key
-----------value
```

I want to access the list of object(s) out of it.

```
  <!-- Here keyvalue is not possible on groupedItemMap -->
<div *ngFor="let group of groupedItemMap.entries()">   
    <span>{{ group.key }}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let items of group| keyvalue">
        <span>{{ items.key }}</span>
        <div *ngFor="let item of items.value">
            <span>{{ item.id }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use it without `keyvalue` on `groupedItemMap` I can only access it with 4 `*ngFor` loops and `map.entries()` which loops all items in my html tag.

[image: Map]

Answer (score 1):

You possibly need to use `keyvalue` for both the loops. Try the following

```html
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let first of groupedItemMap">
 <div *ngFor="let second of first | keyvalue">
   <div *ngFor="let item of second.value | keyvalue">
     <!-- Here `item.value` is an array. So you possibly need another *ngFor. Test with `json` pipe -->
     <strong innerHTML="{{ item.key }} x {{ item.value | highlight: highlight }}">
     </strong>
     <span class="text-description margin-bottom-5"
         innerHTML="{{ 'number' | translate }}: {{ item.number|highlight:highlight }}"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If I use `keyvalue` in both loops I will get a compiler error. Still the same error if I added another loop, even with `second.value`.